# How to Internationalize Sphinx (i18n)

Tags: internationalization, locale, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

From the defaults following an execution of `sphinx-quickstart`, how do I get language-specific directories like what's used by Read The Docs?

I'm starting a new Sphinx documentation site that's hosted by GitHub Pages, built with GitHub Actions, and using the Read The Docs theme. Basically I'm trying to re-create Read The Docs but without ads or server-side search.

I won't be able to actually translate anything for a long time, but I do want to make sure that my new project is ready to be translated at a later time. Most specifically, I want to make sure that permalinks to my documentation will not change after I add translations. To that end, I'd like to make my documentation URL include the language in the URL (`/en/stable/`), for example:

- https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I followed the [Sphinx Guide to Internationalization](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/intl.html) and set the `language` and `locale_dirs` variables in `conf.py`:

```
language = 'en'
locale_dirs = ['locale/']
gettext_compact = True
```

Unfortunately, after the changes above, `make html` and `make -e SPHINXOPTS="-D language='en'" html` still produce files without the `en` subdirectory

```
user@host:~/docs$ tree -L 2 _build
_build
├── doctrees
│   ├── environment.pickle
│   └── index.doctree
└── html
    ├── genindex.html
    ├── index.html
    ├── objects.inv
    ├── search.html
    ├── searchindex.js
    ├── _sources
    └── _static
```

Am I missing something or is the documentation missing something? How do I setup a fresh Sphinx install with the defaults to build to language-specific html with `make`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The undocumented truth is that sphinx doesn't do this. In fact, sphinx i18n functionality stops-short of a workflow for building all your language-specific directories. It's implicit that you have to design & wrap `sphinx-build` with your own scripts to set this up.

To translate your sphinx reST files to another language, you don't have to update your '.rst' files themselves. Sphinx already understands what a block of text looks like, and it can divide-up heading strings, captions, double-newline-separated paragraphs, etc into unique "source strings" (msgid), and put them into '.pot' source-language files and '.po' destination-language files.

First, run `make gettext` from the 'docs/' directory. This tells sphinx to parse your reST files and automatically find a bunch of strings-to-be-translated and give them a unique `msgid`.

```
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages$ cd docs/
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ ls
autodoc.rst  buildDocs.sh  conf.py.orig  locales   Makefile
_build       conf.py       index.rst     make.bat  _static
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ 
 
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ make gettext
Running Sphinx v1.8.4
making output directory...
building [gettext]: targets for 0 template files
building [gettext]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
Hello Worldrces... [ 50%] autodoc                                               
reading sources... [100%] index                                                 
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                  
writing message catalogs... [100%] index                                        
build succeeded.
 
The message catalogs are in _build/gettext.
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
```

The above execution should create the following files

```
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ ls _build/gettext/
autodoc.pot  index.pot
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
```

Here's a snippet from '_build/gettext/index.pot' showing two strings on our documentation's main page that we'll translate from English to Spanish.

```
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ grep -m2 -A2 .rst _build/gettext/index.pot 
#: ../../index.rst:7
msgid "Welcome to helloWorld's documentation!"
msgstr ""
--
#: ../../index.rst:9
msgid "Contents:"
msgstr ""
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
```

Next, let's tell sphinx to prepare some Spanish destination-language '.po' files from our above-generated source-lananguage '.pot' files.

Before proceeding with this step, you'll need to install `sphinx-intl` and the python `Stemmer` module. If you're using a Debian-based distro, you can do so with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install -y sphinx-intl python3-stemmer
```

Execute the following command to prepare our Spanish-specific translation files.

```
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ sphinx-intl update -p _build/gettext -l es
Create: locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/index.po
Create: locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/autodoc.po
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
```

The above execution created two '.po' files: one for each of our '.pot' source-language files, which correlate directly to each of our two '.rst' files (index.rst and autodoc.rst). Perfect.

If we grep the new Spanish-specific 'docs/locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/index.po' file, we see it has the same contents as the source '.pot' file.

```
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ grep -m2 -A2 .rst locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/index.po 
#: ../../index.rst:7
msgid "Welcome to helloWorld's documentation!"
msgstr ""
--
#: ../../index.rst:9
msgid "Contents:"
msgstr ""
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
```

These language-specific '.po' files are where we actually do the translating. If you're a large project, then you'd probably want to use a special program or [service](https://www.transifex.com/) to translate these files. But, for clarity, we'll just edit the files directly.

```
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ perl -pi -0e "s^(msgid \"Welcome to helloWorld's documentation\!\"\n)msgstr \"\"^\1msgstr \"¡Bienvenido a la documentación de helloWorld\!\"^" locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/index.po
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ perl -pi -0e "s^(msgid \"Contents:\"\n)msgstr \"\"^\1msgstr \"Contenidos:\"^" locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/index.po
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ 
 
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ grep -m2 -A2 .rst locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/index.po 
#: ../../index.rst:7
msgid "Welcome to helloWorld's documentation!"
msgstr "¡Bienvenido a la documentación de helloWorld!"
--
#: ../../index.rst:9
msgid "Contents:"
msgstr "Contenidos"
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
```

As you can see, the above execution filled-in the contents of `msgstr ""` with the Spanish translation of the corresponding `msgid` line above it in the original (English) language.

Now let's build two versions of our html static content: [1] in English and [2] in Spanish.

```
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ sphinx-build -b html . _build/html/en -D language='en'
Running Sphinx v1.8.4
loading translations [en]... done
making output directory...
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building : targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
Hello Worldrces... [ 50%] autodoc                                               
reading sources... [100%] index                                                 
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                  
generating indices... genindex py-modindex
highlighting module code... [100%] helloWorld                                   
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.
 
The HTML pages are in _build/html/en.
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
 
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ sphinx-build -b html . _build/html/es -D language='es'
Running Sphinx v1.8.4
loading translations [es]... done
making output directory...
building [mo]: targets for 1 po files that are out of date
writing output... [100%] locales/es/LC_MESSAGES/index.mo                        
building : targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
Hello Worldrces... [ 50%] autodoc                                               
reading sources... [100%] index                                                 
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                  
generating indices... genindex py-modindex
highlighting module code... [100%] helloWorld                                   
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in Spanish (code: es) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.
 
The HTML pages are in _build/html/es.
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
 
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$ firefox _build/html/en/index.html _build/html/es/index.html &
[1] 12134
user@host:~/rtd-github-pages/docs$
```

The `firefox` command in the above execution should open your browser with two tabs: (1) in English and (2) in Spanish.

For more information, see this article on [how to setup internationalization in Sphinx](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2020/07/23/sphinx-rtd-github-pages-2/).

Comment: You may also want to look into using rinoh for generating PDFs with sphinx https://github.com/maltfield/rtd-github-pages/blob/347ec2ed9522d3b5ec6e3e89f0d53bdcee86788b/docs/buildDocs.sh#L74-L77